# Coda issues with FTP/SFTP login

Tags: ftp, sftp, coda

I've been looking over the last two days for a solution to this issue, but am, unfortunately, misereably failing. **I've just installed Coda 2.5.11** and have a basic issue with its FTP its operations. That is, **I'm not able to connect to my server**.

The erros I get are:

[when using FTP] - *Server said: login incorrect* (which is not true)

[when using SFTP] - *Server said: The user name or passowrd was not accepted by the server (d'oh)*

I have found that similar issues had been reported earlier, but am not sure how to match it with my case:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coda-users/ra-P5RZMKJ8
http://michael.grunewalder.com/2012/06/06/coda-2-connecting-with-sftp-finally/

And I have no idea how to adress it myself.

Just to add, the FTP server (login, password) works well when I login using webFTP.

Answer (score 2):

Does your FTP username include an @-symbol?
In this case login is always incorrect. Coda uses OS X libs for connection to FTP-Servers, which fails escaping the @-symbol.

I already reported this issue to Coda support a few month ago.